# Connecting to my database from a VM compute engine

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, google-compute-engine, ovh, clouddb

I have a node application on compute engine using Sequelize to connect to my database.
But when I do it I find myself with the error:

```
SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

I added the fixed IP of my VM in the whitelist of my database.

I try locally and it works. But since compute engine it does not work

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I did not indicate the correct port when connecting to my database